# Split dot or comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

How I can write dot or comma in this code:

```
var mytext = text.split('.');
```

I want to say split (dot or comma), I don't know how I can write "or" between dot and comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a regular expression which looks for dot or comma.

```js
var text = 'foo,bar.baz',
    array = text.split(/[.,]/);

console.log(array);
```